# ¿Cómo puedo cerrar una ventana creara desde otra función?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo dos funciones:

```
function crearVentana() {
                var ventana=open("","","width=500px,height=500px");
            }

function cerrarVentana() {
                ventana.close();
            }
```

La función crearVentana() funciona, pero al ejecutar la función cerrarVentana() me dice que la varaible "ventana" no existe, sé que es porque "ventana" es una variable local de la función cerrarVentana(), pero ahí esta mi duda, cómo puedo cerrar una ventana desde otra función?

Comment: Declara la variable fuera de las funciones `var ventana;` para abrir omites `var` y con eso debería funcionar.

Comment: MALA PRACTICA: También puedes eliminar la palabra `var` y de ese modo dicha variable será declarada en el contexto global y no en el de la función. De este modo funcionaría, pero lo más recomendable es hacer lo que te comenta @Triby (que es lo mismo pero más expresivo).

Comment: No lo entiendo, la variable ventana la declaro fuera de las funciones no? y en la función crearVentana hago el open y en la de cerrarVentana hago el close ?

Answer (score 0):

1.- Lo que te recomiendo es que declares tu variable **ventana** fuera de las 2 funciones, esto hará que tu variable puedas utilizarla a lo largo de todo tu programa te muestro un ejemplo práctico con codigo para que puedas entenderlo mejor:

```
//Declaramos la variable ventana

let ventana;

function crearVentana() {
 ventana = open("","","width=500px,height=500px");
}

function cerrarVentana() {
  ventana.close();
}

//Al darle click al boton Abrir ventana mandamos a llamar tu funcion crearVentana()
document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click',()=>{
  crearVentana();
})



//Al darle click al boton Cerrar ventana mandamos a llamar tu funcion cerrarVentana()
document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click',()=>{
  cerrarVentana();
})
```

2.- Esta de mas decir que tienes que conceder permisos para poder mostrar ventanas. Te recomiendo que investigues sobre ventanas modales, es menos agresivo para el usuario y buena practica.